# add multiple UIBarButtonItems to UINavigationItem in Storyboard?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5

[image]

It is easy to add a single UIBarButton item as you can see here in my Storyboard.  But I want to add several and it seems I cannot using the Storyboard?

Which is annoying because then I lose the whole nice overview of the Storyboard and it's Segue's.

Is this the case?  First project using Storyboards so I figured I might be missing something.

Comment: if you want to have more than a "left" and "right" bar button item, I think you might have to create your own (or subclassed) UINavigationBar where multiple buttons can be specified & drawn.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Multiple UINavigationBar buttons on each side are supported in iOS5. You don't need to subclass. However I don't know how you manage them in Storyboards :(

Comment: @Slee did you find a solution ? I am currently in the same case as you. Many native apps have multiple buttons (mail for example). For now I use the trick of putting a toolbar, hiding it and copying the buttons onto the navigation bar. But it is a trick. Is there any clean solution ?

Comment: No, I was hoping there would be a clean way to do this with Storyboards but I have not found a solution myself

Comment: Not possible even in Xcode 5. Go to https://bugreport.apple.com and open a radar, requesting the feature.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

In XCode 4.6 (at least), you can drag a plain view onto the navigation bar (on whichever side you want multiple buttons), then drag a toolbar on top of that.   Once you've done that, you can place multiple bar button items on the toolbar, and wire them up to actions / segues, etc, as normal.   Make sure you have the view and toolbar both set up for default (transparent) background color.

Comment: +1 for Dan L.  Awesome answer.  Exactly what I needed.  Thanks!

Comment: Select "Clip subviews" on the view to get rid of the grey line above the toolbar.

Comment: I just found out that you do not have to add toolbar and barButtonItems.
But you can simply add UIButtons into added UIVIew.

Answer (score 3):

In Xcode 7 you can finally just drag multiple UIBarButtonItems to the UINavigationItem directly in Interface Builder.

See WWDC 2015 Session 407 video titled:

> Implementing UI Designs in Interface Builder

https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=407

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
    -(void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIBarButtonItem *editBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit target:self action:@selector(editAction)];

    UIBarButtonItem *saveBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSave target:self action:@selector(saveAction)];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:editBarButtonItem, saveBarButtonItem, nil];   
}
```

We also need to implement the methods editAction and saveAction.

```
-(void)editAction
{

    NSLog(@"edit button clicked");
}

-(void)saveAction
{

    NSLog(@"save button clicked");
}
```